# Update query issue with selecting joins

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables with two fields codes and stations.

| codes | station |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 211 |
|  |  |
| 2 | 511 |
| 3 | 618 |
| 5 | 711 |
|  |  |
| 7 | 911 |

| codes1 | station |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 5 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 7 |  |
| 8 |  |
| 9 |  |

I want to update the stations to output

| codes1 | station |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 211 |
| 1 | 211 |
| 2 | 511 |
| 3 | 618 |
| 5 | 711 |
| 6 |  |
| 7 |  |
| 8 |  |
| 9 | 911 |

I already tried right join but it is giving me Total of both rows.

Comment: Edit question to show attempt SQL. Why would there be any Total? This looks like a simple JOIN of two tables with an UPDATE of one field. Why doesn't the output show 911 with line 7?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a based solution and you have table1 then table2 like this:

| codes | station |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 211 |
| 2 | 511 |
| 3 | 618 |
| 5 | 711 |
| 7 | 911 |

| codes1 | station |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 5 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 7 |  |
| 8 |  |
| 9 |  |

Then using the Access query designer create an update query similar to:

[image: query designer]

The query designer generates the following structured query language which you can see in the structured query language pane.

```
UPDATE Table2, Table1 SET Table2.station = [Table1].[station]
WHERE (((Table1.codes)=[Table2].[codes1]));
```

Now to avoid a possible problem.  If you run this action query directly from the query designer it will not work properly.  Close the query designer then run the query for instance by double clicking it and you will get:

[image]